# PhoneGap Build: image will not load (new Image())

Tags: html, cordova, adobe, phonegap-build

I have made a game, but some of the grapics will not load in PhoneGap it works fine in Chrome and Safari. 2 of the importan images is transperant (when i opening the game the background is black because it transparant).

What should i do?

Answer (score 1):

Use [debug.phonegap.com](http://debug.phonegap.com) to watch the logs. You will see an error in the logs, telling you what is wrong.

For details see [documentation](http://build.phonegap.com/docs/advanced-debugging).

Comment: I have already tried it. There is no errors. I thinks that it is a bug in PhoneGap.

Answer (score 1):

Are the images being loaded from the internet? If so, have you added permission / a whitelist to load from the URL in your config.xml file? Eg. http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html#Domain%20Whitelist%20Guide